# Overwriting Setters for Retain Properties

Tags: objective-c, properties

Is there any way to avoid this kind of code when overwriting the default setter for a `retain` property?

```
-(void)setMasterViewController:(UIViewController *)newMaster {
    [newMaster retain];
    [masterViewController release];
    masterViewController = newMaster;

    // do custom stuff on set
}
```

Is there any way to access the default setter, something like:

```
-(void)setMasterViewController:(UIViewController *)newMaster {
    [defaultSetMasterViewController:newMaster];
    // do custom stuff
}
```

This would keep the code DRYer. The way I'm doing it currently, the fact that it's a `retain` property is mentioned twice.

Comment: not really an answer but I like to make sure that newMaster != masterViewController before going ahead

Comment: @Nathan Day, I'm assuming they could be the same, hence the retain before the release. If there's any BEHAVIOR involved in setting, it has to be idempotent, otherwise it should be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreData generates primitive setters, but in general there's no such affordance. You may be able to replace custom setters with key-value observing in some cases, but the solution to your specific question is probably "use ARC" if you can limit support to 10.6+/4.3+. It will handle the retain/release stuff on your behalf.

Comment: Or "switch to ARC" as the case might be :) Thanks +1

Comment: If it's easier on your project, you can switch just that module to ARC by adding `-fobjc-arc` to the compiler flags for that module in the Build Phases tab of your project (the Compile Sources build phase to be precise).

Comment: Thanks Joe, that really helps. I will probably convert the entire thing to ARC bit by bit.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, because the setter has to perform the actual setting. You could try doing this using key-value observing if you want to keep the original setter.

However... Yes, if you're using [ARC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)! If you have a `@property (strong)`, then when you simply say `masterViewController = newMaster` ARC will use `objc_storeStrong`, which:

> Performs the complete sequence for assigning to a `__strong` object of non-block type. Equivalent to the following code:
>
> ```
> id objc_storeStrong(id *object, id value) {
>   value = [value retain];
>   id oldValue = *object;
>   *object = value;
>   [oldValue release];
>   return value;
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks +1. Could you cite the citation, please?

Comment: Yes, it's from the link I posted.

Comment: thanks for that, great stuff, and great to see the underlying method... I wonder if `id *object` is applicable to other contexts in Obj-C. It seems like it allows the caller to refer to the variable itself, not the object that it's referencing.

Comment: Um, well, `id *` is just a pointer to a type that can be written `id`, which includes `NSStuff *`, so it can be used equivalently to `NSStuff **`. You should read up on pointers.

Comment: just confirming this: the `objc_storeStrong` is called even if I skip the setter entirely then? ARC knows that the ivar is `__strong` based on the property itself?

Comment: Thanks, it seems that way too.